# How can I whitelist my backend hosted on Railway, in my MongoDB Atlas cluster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, whitelist, railway

I'm hosting my backend code on Railway, and using MongoDB Atlas to store my data.

For development I had my local IP address whitelisted. But now when my backend has been deployed and I went to make it public, it can't connect to my Atlas cluster because it is making the request from a different IP address that isn't whitelisted.
I can make my cluster be open to be accessed from any IP but I don't want that.

When it comes to Railway, I can't understand where do I find the IP address that I need to whitelist on Railway?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for https://railway.app ? I am not too familiar with it but based off the help page / common questions https://railway.app/help , it states the following:

> Can I get my workload's IP Address?
>
> > We don't provide static IPs at this time. This on our roadmap.

Have you tried contacting Railway support or similar to find out the information regarding the IP addresses? Maybe they're on a particular range that you could add to your network access list in Atlas instead of allowing all IP addresses.

Comment: Yeah railway.app. That's weird, so thy expect their customers to just whitelist everything if they want to use their service? I'll try contact them but also might just look for a different service. Thanks!

Comment: No idea - It does state it's on the roadmap so I assume it's a heavily requested capability but this is my assumption just based off the help page rather than using the app itself. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

On 'Network Access' tab, select Add IP Address and click 'Allow from anywhere'.